# Are valid `tf.matmul` arguments described correctly in the TensorFlow documentation?

Tags: tensorflow, documentation, matrix-multiplication, tensor

Maybe I'm confused about what "inner" and "outer" tensor dimensions are, but the documentation for `tf.matmul` puzzles me:

> The inputs must be matrices (or tensors of rank > 2, representing
>   batches of matrices), with matching inner dimensions, possibly after
>   transposition.

Isn't it the case that R-rank arguments need to have matching (or no) R-2 outer dimensions, and that (as in normal matrix multiplication) the Rth, inner dimension of the first argument must match the R-1st dimension of the second. That is, in

```
A = tf.constant(..., shape=[a, ..., z, p, x])
B = tf.constant(..., shape=[a', ..., z', x', q]) 
C = tf.matmul(A, B)
```

The outer dimensions `a, ..., z` must be identical to `a', ..., z'` (or not exist), and `x` and `x'` must match (while `p` and `q` can be anything).

Or put another way, shouldn't the docs say:

> The inputs must, following any transpositions, be tensors of rank ≥ 2 where the inner 2 dimensions specify valid matrix multiplication arguments, and any further outer dimensions match.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: @Mogsdad How is the meta you link to related to this question?

Comment: Your question focuses on the documentation, and offers a correction - just the sort of conversation you'd have when reporting a bug to a vendor. (Reflected in the vendor response.) So - reported problem to vendor, vendor responded, and you got what you needed. However, the question provides no long-term help for anyone else, so is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Mogsdad That’s quote a stretch, but a good effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [fixed in a recent merge](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b7892a30f389d5ac3cdc374d371082585e5809ec). The documentation will now read:

> The inputs must, following any transpositions, be tensors of rank >= 2
>   where the inner 2 dimensions specify valid matrix multiplication
>   arguments, and any further outer dimensions match.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed docs tell nothing about transposition: notice that [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) has parameters which allow arguments to be transposed. So if you specify some of them as true, *inner 2 dimensions specify valid matrix multiplication arguments, possibly after transposition*.

Apart from that, you are right that the first R-2 dimensions must be the same.

So, in my opinion the documentation describes it correctly, but can be better.

Comment: I've edited my suggestion.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius can you tell what exactly is unclear in the docs? The role of transposition is simple if you pass `transpose_a = True` it is the same as instead of passing `a` you would pass `tf.tranpose(a)`

Comment: Yes, I've added transposition to the suggestion. What's unclear is that they appear to be wrong (that's the question): "matching inner dimensions" is neither correct (if I've got inner and outer right, or unless transpose is True by default for both arguments) nor complete (p and q can be anything).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I assume that by 'matching' they mean 'being valid for multiplication'. In this case it is correct. If by 'matching' they mean 'being the same', then it is wrong. Also I am not aware of the terms 'inner/outer' dimension for tensors.

Comment: Yes, so the two critical terms here have issues: "matching" is ambiguous (actually wrong I'd argue, since matching has a pretty explicit meaning that's not merely "valid for multiplication"); and we don't (either of us) know for sure what "inner/outer" mean (but I think the docs have reversed).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius after working with tf's documentation I will say that it is suited for a person who knows the theory and math. Otherwise almost everything is ambiguous (einsum, conv2d, conv2dtranspose, ...). Whether this is right/wrong is not for me to decide. I just explained you that your understanding is correct.